# Adding processes at runtime in activiti using Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, activiti

I am new in Activiti workflow framework for Spring-boot and I searched many website with no luck. What i want to achieve is that I want to add processes to activiti's bpmn file dynamically which is located at resources/processes folder in Spring-boot. In other words, the users of the application will be able to create their own workflow using REST request during runtime, that is, the service will never be shut down or restarted. How can i solve this kind of goal and dynamically change .xml file which is used by activiti without any need of restarting? I could not find any example or guide for this kind of application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily update an existing process definition or load a new process definition using the ReST API documented below:
https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#_create_a_new_deployment

If you are using Activiti 6 Process Apps you will need to use ReST API that is part of the activiti-app UI module.